# How do I make links that were in the menu be on the nav bar on bigger screens?

Tags: html, css, menu, header, nav

There are links that were shown on the side of the page as a menu when a button that was in the `header` was clicked. I want the button to be hidden and for those links to show up in the `header` instead. But if hide the button, the links do not show up, regardless of if I make the `display: block` or not. The only thing that happens is that the button is gone, but so are the links.

I have JavaScript code that hides and shows the links when the button is clicked

How do I change the position of the links?

```css
header {
  height: 3.4rem;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.right i {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  /* margin-left: 4rem; */
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .right i {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .top-menu {
    display: flex;
    top: 0;
  }
  .header-container {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <img src="img/user.png" alt="">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-xl"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark fa-xl"></i>
    <div class="top-menu">
      <a href="">Premium</a>
      <a href="">Support</a>
      <a href="">Download</a>
      <div class="menu-line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
      <a href="">Account</a>
      <a href="">Log out</a>
    </div>
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want links on Nav Bar to show when the site is viewed via PC or Laptop screen. And you want the links to collapse in button when site is viewed via mobile.

When viewed on PC Screen:
[image: When viewed on PC:]

[image: When viewed on Mobile:]

I did it with Bootstrap, you can also use jQuery for simplicity.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggler1" aria-controls="navbarToggler1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler1">
        <div id="right-menu" class="col-md-3">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

**Using simple jQuery**

```css
#show{
  display:none;
}
#content{
  display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
  div{
    display:none;
  }
  #show{
    display:inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>
      pricing
    </li>
    <li>
      features
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      pricing
    </li>
    <li>
      features
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#show").click(function()
  {
    $("#content").toggle();
  });  
</script>
```

[Live Result with Code](https://codepen.io/nisoojadhav/pen/BaYjmbr)

Comment: I don't know how to use these libraries properly yet. Is there a way  to this is in html or css or vanilla javasciprt?

Comment: https://codepen.io/nisoojadhav/pen/BaYjmbr